# EF6 : 2x a one to one relationship gives error "Unable to determine principal end of association"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem with the Entity Framework that I can't figure out.

I have a `Module` class that links to another `Module` (a one-to-one relationship) in two ways.

Code:

```
public class Module {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id {get;set;} /* primary key */
    public Guid? OtherModule1 {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("OtherModule1")]
    public Module OtherModule {get;set;}

    public Guid? OtherModule2 {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("OtherModule2")]
    public Module OtherModule2 {get;set;}
}
```

This gives the error that the principal end of the association cannot be determined.

```
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Module' and 'Module'
```

I understand what the error means, but here's the thing. The relationship with `OtherModule1` has always existed without a problem. This code works:

```
public class Module {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id {get;set;} /* primary key */
    public Guid? OtherModule1 {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("OtherModule1")]
    public Module OtherModule {get;set;}
}
```

There is no Fluent configuration present on this table 
Now, if I add a new column, `OtherModule2` and link it in the exact same way, this error pops up.
Does anyone have an idea of how to handle this?

**TL/DR**: one table has two foreign keys to the same table. One foreign key is handled correctly while the other is not.

Comment: Can you post the working model (with single FK)? Also the fluent configuration code if any.

Comment: There is no fluent configuration on this table. Updated the code to show the working model with single FK. It's the same class, but without `OtherModule2` .

Comment: What is confusing me is that you said *one-to-one* relationship while the "working" model  creates *one-to-many* relationship. So what it should be - to one or to many?

Comment: One Module contains the ID of exactly one other Module. Maybe if you inverse that relationship, it's not per se a one-to-one relationship anymore? Is that what you mean? That one Module can be included in many other Modules? Then I guess it's a one-to-many technically, although I will never lookup in that way. I'll have a Module and read what other Module is referenced.

Answer (score 1):

The working model by convention defines one-to-many unidirectional (with only navigation property at the many side) relationship. It's equivalent of the following fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Module>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.OtherModule)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.OtherModule1);
```

When you add a second FK / navigation property pair (I've renamed the FK property because you can't have 2 properties with the same name in the class):

```
public class Module
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } /* primary key */

    public Guid? OtherModule1 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OtherModule1")]
    public Module OtherModule { get; set; }

    [Column("OtherModule2")]
    public Guid? OtherModule2_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OtherModule2_Id")]
    public Module OtherModule2 { get; set; }
}
```

EF cannot automatically determine the relationships - it could be 2 unidirectional one-to-many or 1 bidirectional one-to-one, hence the error.

There is no way to specify that with data annotations in this case, so you need to use fluent configuration to either fully configure the relationships, or when combined with data annotations, to simply specify the cardinality and the navigation properties involved.

The following fluent configuration is sufficient to resolve the issue for the above data annotated model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Module>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.OtherModule)
    .WithMany();

modelBuilder.Entity<Module>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.OtherModule2)
    .WithMany();
```